# Cert-manager generates three certificates in tls.crt file

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I have established kubernetes cluster on one of the private hosting machine with public IP. I installed a few applications there and NGINX as the ingress controller. I would like to make a reachable my services outside of the cluster and be accessible with the specific domain. I installed cert-manager via helm and requested certificate via letsencrypt-prod, (validated domain via http-01 resolver) everything looks perfect (clusterissuer. certificate, certificaterequest, challenge) but from some reason, my TLS secret after BASE64 decoding - contains three certificates in the following order:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

which is incorrect, as far as I know - it should be only two certificates (instead of 3), any ideas what can be wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with it. You are seeing the root certificate, intermediate certificate, and your subscriber certificate.

It's actually normal for certificate authorities to use intermediate certificates.

You can read about it here: https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Comment: ok, but how can I use this certificate in my TLS secret to provide it to ingress?
there is problem because i am getting SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when I have set up this certificate in the front of ingress of each hosts associated with this certificate

Comment: this is a separate question. if you post your ingress definitions in a new question, i'll try and help there